# How to single out point location in Geometry node 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes

I could do it in the previous Geometry nodes with Attribute vector math, and then multiplying the position with 1,0,0 (for x axis).

But the new system with fields and all seems to be different. Could you please tell me how to do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you right, you want this?

[image]

So after the separate xyz node, you got your x-value.